# Where can I find step-by-step MySQL Replication tutorial?

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-workbench, windows-server

Am looking to have a master MySQL update a slave via the internet. Would like to try to use Workbench if possible (or some other free method). Both boxes are Windows 2003 servers and can see each other across the Internet. The slave would never need to update the master. I don't need this act as a true failover cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL manual would be a great place to start - or even Google?

There is a page in the MySQL Manual called - [How to setup replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html).

Comment: Thanks Steve. I did Google ahead of time and was hoping that someone here would point me towards something "distilled."

Comment: @Kendor does the step by step guide in the MySQL manual (I liked to) not fulfil your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Check Out

> High Performance MySQL, 3rd Edition

by Baron Schwartz, Peter Zaitsev, and Vadim Tkachenko

Has everything you need.